# MKNetworkKit caching whoes

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsurlconnection, mknetworkkit

My app enables multiple users to log in and out. Our server uses a typical REST API. I am monitoring the MKNetworkKit output via curlCommandString.

I'll log in with an account, make some queries (say, getting a list of assets)... works great.

Then I'll log out and log in with a different account. I'll make the same request but get results as though the first user was logged in (friend list from the first user).

However, when I execute the CURL command that MKNetworkKit prints to the console (in my own terminal), the server returns an empty list like it should. This is evidence that MKNetworkKit is holding on to some cache or something.

Here is a typical procedure:

1.) log in with account a and retrieve assets (this user has 20 assets, and 20 are returned by MKNetwork Kit):
// The curl output for user 1:

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Auth-Token: 96cg7oH8LDDPYS......" "http://myserver/api/v3/assets?date=2013-07-02T14%3A49%3A08-0700"
```

20 are returned by this curl command.

2.) Log out:

- destroy the storage of the tokens
- cancel all operations of MKNetworkKit
- empty cache of MKNetworkKit
- destroy the instance of MKNetworkKit

3.) Log in with account B and retrieve list of assets (this user has no assets, but 20 are returned by MKNetworkKit)
// The CURL output for user 2:

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Auth-Token: 3HwN15xJUzKDPr......" "http://myserver/api/v3/assets?date=2013-07-02T14%3A49%3A08-0700"
```

This curl command returns no assets, like I am expecting.

What have I done to turn caching off? It appears that it should be off by default. 
I placed a breakpoint inside MKNetworkKit to ensure that the isCachingEnabled is returning false (I never set it to on).

Am I missing some sort of step in my log out process?

Comment: How does the cache control-headers look like for the response? There can be intermediate proxies on the Internet, caching without you knowing, unless you set "Cache-Control:private" server side.

Comment: Yea the header or params are being cached. But not by MKNetwork. So it's either a bug in your code, a Proxy server messing with it, or some third party code messing with the URL request for gawd knows what reason..

Comment: Yep, it was a "bug" in my code (inherited when hired). Turns out there was a caching store which I overlooked. Thanks.